# Why are matplotlib subplots so far away from eachother?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

So in general when I'm doing subplots of multiple rows, the result appears ugly : the distance between each row is much bigger than the distance between each column

Here is an example in which i'm showing on a 2*4 subplot grid the same image contained in `Y[...,0]`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(8):
  plt.subplot(2,4,i+1)
  plt.imshow(Y[...,0])
plt.show()
```

[Screenshot of the result](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/899303686633840720/949526634464149544/unknown.png). As you can see, there is a big white space between the two rows.
Is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: For some reason when I set the number of rows to 3 it does not do that at all, it looks very nice.

Comment: `imshow` plots squares. You're creating a 2x4 grid in a 10x10 figure, so each subplot is roughly 5x2.5. That means `imshow` creates 2.5x2.5 squares inside 5x2.5 subplots, leaving lots of vertical space.

Comment: Use something like `plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))`. Also call `plt.tight_layout()` after the loop before `plt.show()`